# How to get navigation starting immediately via app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `Angular` / `Javascript` / `Ionic` to open the native `Apple Maps` and navigate to the address that I have set, but I can't get it working. What it does right now, is that it opens the native Maps and that's it. I need to manually click on "navigate" in Apple Maps so that it actually starts the navigation.

What do I want? I want it to navigate **immediately**. So, what I want is this:

[image]

What I have right now, is this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
$scope.openNavigator = function() {
  var geoString = '';

  if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
          url = 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=' + encodeURIComponent(address);
  }

  window.open(geoString, '_system');
}
```

How can I update my snippet to do so? Is there something else I need to do to get the immediate navigation working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation will work when you give source and destination inputs:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?saddr=Cupertino&daddr=San+Francisco
```

for example

```
url = 'http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr='+sourceAddr+'&daddr='+destAddr;
```